# I was told this is not a math puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

But the puzzle is supposedly "Why are those numbers in that order?"

8, 18, 11, 15, 5, 4, 14, 9, 19, 1, 7, 17, 6, 16, 10, 13, 3, 12, 20, 2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe this is simply

> All numbers from 1 to 20 arranged into alphabetical order when written as words.

Comment: I think that may be it!

Comment: @DavidWilkins So, will you divulge that you didn't solve it yourself? :D

Comment: I did indeed divulge that.  The person who gave me the puzzle was not happy that I enlisted help LOL